# Bash script to download HTML from server A and POST it to server B

Tags: bash, escaping

There is a website in a local network. I want to write a bash script which will download the HTML from the local website and send it to an external server, where a PHP script can read it from `$_POST`:

```
html=$(wget --post-data="str=data" -qO- http://192.168.1.8/reg/index.php)
#so far so good, and $html contains data I want to send to my website
wget --post-data="html=$html" -qO- http://mywebsite.com/test.php
```

In `test.php` the data always come malformed.

Is there any way to properly escape `$html`, or should I totally change my approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Encode your HTML using Base64 before sending the request:

   ```
   html=$( wget --post-data="str=data" -qO- http://192.168.1.8/reg/index.php | base64 )
   ```
2. URL-encode your POST data.

   Unfortunately, `wget` will not URL-encode the post data for you. If
   available, you could use `curl` which provides URL-encoding for the
   POST request:

   ```
   curl -S -d "str=${html}" --data-urlencode -- http://mywebsite.com/test.php
   ```

   If `curl`is not available, you need to replace all `+` in `$html`
   with `%2B` and all `/` with `%2F` before posting to `test.php`, e.g.
   using:

   ```
   html=$( sed -e 's/+/%2B/g' -e 's/\//%2F/g' <<< "$html" )
   ```
3. In `test.php`, you pass `$_POST['str']` to `base64_decode()` before 
   using it, see its
   [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: I have edited my script:
`html=$( wget --post-data="str=asdfg" -qO- http://192.168.1.8/reg/index.html | base64)
return=$(wget --post-data="html=$html" -qO- http://mywebsite.com/test.php)
echo "$return"`
test.php contains only one line: `echo base64_decode($_POST['html']);`
The return is somehow malformated. See yourself: http://postimg.org/image/xchhi6deb/

Comment: @ViliamJobko: I suspect your terminal cannot display the output. Is the output of `test.php` the same in your web browser and your terminal? Can you try getting your locale settings with `locale` and the character encoding from the web server and/or HTML page with `wget -S -O - http://192.168.1.8/reg/index.html 2>&1 | grep charset`?

Comment: After hours spent messing with charsets, $_GET, $_POST and everything I noticed, that the output of base64 include symbols '+'. But when I pass the output to the website using $_POST, the website decodes  '+' as ' ' (space). So I need to do `$html = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $_POST['html']))` in the test.php.

Comment: @ViliamJobko: Of course, form data has to be URL-encoded by the client (which turns `+` into `%2B`). Curl does that for you if you give the `--data-urlencode` switch on the command line. I'm sorry, I completely forgot about that. I'll edit my answer so the next reader will see.

Comment: @ViliamJobko: I've edited my answer to address your `+` problem on the client side (by either using curl for the POST or replacing `+` and `/` in the html before posting). Note that `/` can occur in Base64 as well.

Comment: Thank you for update. The problem was that I want to run this script from my dd-wrt based router, which hasn't got curl.
In the end I found out that dd-wrt is also missing base64. Do you know any workaround for it? If not, I will just run script from my computer.

Comment: @ViliamJobko: There are base64 implementations for Bash: https://www.google.at/#q=base64+implementation+in+bash - I haven't tried any of these, but they might just work for you.

Comment: And it could be a good idea to mention major constraints like "has to run on dd-wrt" at the beginning ;-)